# Debian 10 VNC Server Displays Grey Screen with X Using XFCE

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

I have tried several suggestion solutions elsewhere online, but nothing is working yet. Still getting just a grey screen with an X when trying to connect to Debian 10 server running tightvnc server with XFCE desktop.

Here's the output of the log.

```
22/09/20 12:12:08 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
22/09/20 12:12:08 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
22/09/20 12:12:08 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
22/09/20 12:12:08 All Rights Reserved.
22/09/20 12:12:08 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
22/09/20 12:12:08 Desktop name 'X' (fbcradiocast1:1)
22/09/20 12:12:08 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
22/09/20 12:12:08 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
xfce4-session: Another session manager is already running

22/09/20 12:12:30 Got connection from client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:30 Using protocol version 3.8
22/09/20 12:12:37 Full-control authentication passed by 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
22/09/20 12:12:37 Using zlib encoding for client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
22/09/20 12:12:37 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/09/20 12:12:37 Pixel format for client 192.168.2.118:
22/09/20 12:12:37   8 bpp, depth 6
22/09/20 12:12:37   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
22/09/20 12:12:37 Using raw encoding for client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
22/09/20 12:12:37 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
22/09/20 12:12:37 Using zlib encoding for client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
22/09/20 12:12:37 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.2.118
22/09/20 12:12:37 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/09/20 12:12:37 Pixel format for client 192.168.2.118:
22/09/20 12:12:37   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
22/09/20 12:12:37   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
22/09/20 12:12:37   no translation needed
22/09/20 12:12:58 Client 192.168.2.118 gone
22/09/20 12:12:58 Statistics:
22/09/20 12:12:58   key events received 0, pointer events 114
22/09/20 12:12:58   framebuffer updates 3, rectangles 52, bytes 30244
22/09/20 12:12:58     cursor shape updates 3, bytes 1668
22/09/20 12:12:58     raw rectangles 1, bytes 16396
22/09/20 12:12:58     zlib rectangles 48, bytes 12180
22/09/20 12:12:58   raw bytes equivalent 3948580, compression ratio 138.178191
```

Here's my xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
unset SEESION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in SEESION_MANAGER